# In Jquery mobile how to disable magnifying glass in phone gap application for iPad?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, cordova, ios7

I have used following CSS to disable context menus (e.g.:- copy,paste etc..),but it is not disabling magnifying glass:-

```
body { 
  -webkit-touch-callout: none ;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

PFA screenshot for reference:-

[image]

Please suggest some solution,Thanks

Comment: Does it help to add the CSS rule: pointer-events: none; ?

Comment: playing devil's advocate: why anger users by disabling native tools on the device?

Comment: no pointer-events: none; didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Well, that should work in theory, but you should set the CSS directly on the Div(s) and elements you don't want the mag glass to appear instead of just the (body). You may need to remove some of those if you want the functionality, eg (input)  ---

```
html, body, div, input, span, object,
form, h1, h2, button, label, a, img {
 -webkit-touch-callout: none ;
 -webkit-user-drag: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
 }
```

Comment: I can see the magnifying lens by long tap on any part of the page

Comment: Its should work, because its works ok with I-phones. Try deleting the browsers cache so it loads the css file again cleanly. Check also your pages and add other elements and Divs to the code above, you need to add everything you have to disable the mag glass.

Comment: On navigating the pages back and forth it again started to show magnifying lens ,Does Jquery mobile removes the style from external css file on page navigation ?

Comment: Not if you have multi-page template. If its single pages then you need that css code in every file you have if you are using a different css files. Add that code to the JQM css file instead and give it a test.